# How do I link a library to be loaded from the local directory?

Tags: c++, linux, gdi+

I am trying to compile and bundle an application I have for Linux that requires a couple of external libs such as libgdiplus. When I try to run the application in an environment that doesn't have GDIPlus installed it fails to find the local copy of libgdiplus.so I have in the next directory as my application.

If I use strace to see what's going on I clearly see it checking a number of locations such as /lib/ /usr/lib/ etc, but never the local directory.

How can I tell my application to search for external libs in the local directory?

Comment: Use LD_PRELOAD or LD_LIBRARY_PATH, see `man ld.so`. However, this means you have to find out the directory where the application is installed first or write a wrapper-script that sets up the environment and then exec's the binary. Using bash, $0 refers to the full path, from which you can derive the directory.

Comment: I'll take a look, however its extremely important that we be able to simply deploy the binary and have it work without any installation or wrapper script requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer. I needed to specify the search path with rpath in the linker like so:

```
-Wl,-rpath,.
```